# How to avoid unsafe assignment from Ref<string> to Ref<string | undefined>?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Vue's `ref` function can create a typed `Ref` object, and the value type can optionally contain `undefined`. Is there a way to set types so that assigning a `Ref<string>` to `Ref<string | undefined>` is prevented by Typescript?

#### Example

Here I create a `Ref<string>` and try to assign `undefined`, which (as expected) causes an error:

```
const s1 = ref('hello') // typed as Ref<string>
s1.value = undefined // causes a TS error as expected: "Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'"
```

However, I can assign this ref to another ref supporting `undefined`, which erases the type check:

```
const s2: Ref<string | undefined> = s1 // IMO unsafe assignment -- how to make this illegal?
s2.value = undefined
const s: string = s1.value // TS thinks that the value is still a string, but actually it's undefined
```

#### My use case

I encountered this problem while writing a function which should (among other things) unset the value of a ref. I'd like to have TS support for only passing refs with valid types:

```
function unsetRef<T>(r: Ref<T | undefined>) {
  r.value = undefined
}

unsetRef(s1) // expected to be ok
unsetRef(s2) // expected to fail, but causes no TS error
```

Comment: For clarity, you are not assigning a ref to another ref: you are assigning a ref to another _variable_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it generic and check if the ref's type includes `undefined`, and if it doesn't include `undefined`, then disallow the call by changing the type to `never`:

```
function unsetRef<T extends Ref<unknown>>(r: undefined extends T["value"] ? T : never) {
```

```
const s1 = ref('hello');

const s2 = ref<string | undefined>("hello")

unsetRef(s1); // error
unsetRef(s2); // okay
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzlApgMwDRwErrgXzjSghDgCIA3AVxXIG4BYAKBbWoDsBjGYCDuJwDOKGLjQAeACpwUADxgoOAEyE50EzgGsOEAO4cAfIYAUUAFyCV6YBxTLZCparhSA2lQCGAG1rkAunAA-K5wlnaUKFAAlIgscMgAdJQ+tHAAvFbKNnbKLPgsLFz8QvBCAIwZyOgmAOQAFije3hC10UyszMUcpXBCAExVqJKlULYA5nAAPlk59qbkjc0Q5NGFzMKi4iYV7SybYjUD7UA)